# Copying values of a 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and I am trying to copy the values of a 2D array to another array
I have the code

```
R=[[0]*3]*3
p=[[1,0.25,0.14],[0.25,1,0.1],[0.14,0.1,1]]  
for i in range(0,3,1):
    for j in range(0,3,1):
        R[i][j]=p[i][j]
print(R)
```

But the output has all the rows of R as the last row of p.
[[0.14, 0.1, 1], [0.14, 0.1, 1], [0.14, 0.1, 1]]
Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps the suggested duplicate is not a direct or clear explanation of your problem. That is, until you check the ids of the the sublists of `R`: `id(R[0])`, `id(R[1])` and `id(R[2])`: they are all the exact same sublist.

Comment: I don't see why this is happening. After the first iteration of the outer loop how can the first row change?

Comment: looks like `R=[[0]*3]*3` is creating a list of references to the same sublist, so any changes change each sublist. Try: `R=[[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `R` array using [[0]*3]*3, you are essentially creating a list with three references to the same inner list [0, 0, 0]. So, when you modify one row of R, you're modifying the underlying list that all the rows point to.

In order to fix the issue you should create a 2D array with distinct inner lists for each row.

Refer the code below :

```
R = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
p = [[1, 0.25, 0.14], [0.25, 1, 0.1], [0.14, 0.1, 1]]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        R[i][j] = p[i][j]

print(R)
```

> Refer to the working code sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Io5W5ES6D)